# Who is Crystal Maiden's favorite poet?

Tags: dota-2

Who is Crystal Maiden's favorite  poet ?
She keep saying that when i'm provoking her rare voice phrases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "Rare" response "Can you guess my... favorite poet?" is a reference to **[Robert Frost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost)** due to his last name.

[Crystal Maiden Trivia](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Maiden#Trivia)